# Change image source created by context.drawimage

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code allow me to draw cross, with its (x,y) coordinates, one by one with 5 seconds of interval , it works fine :

```
  <script src="http://alertifyjs.com/build/alertify.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://alertifyjs.com/build/css/alertify.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://alertifyjs.com/build/css/themes/default.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<div style="width : 75%;margin : auto;">
<canvas id="Canvas" width="954" height="267"></canvas>


<button class="play">Play</button>
<button class="pause">Pause</button>

</div>

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Map sprite
var mapSprite = new Image();
mapSprite.src = "v1.png";
 var array_x = [351,315,353,352,318,485,351,748,568,645,373,350,572,374,650,240,240,320,707,235,402,539,256,410,433,405,353,745,404,320,514,322,692,474,293,418,418,690,237,513,378,478,433,405,285,429,458,622,568,536,564,389,641,534,567,454,575,482,459,539,431,327,464,374,348,520,279,378,509,516,232,744,351,710,481,540,429,642,537,459,513,689,324,463,375,747,431,265,484,591,458,460,485,407,720,483,376,520,691,376,232,413,536,430,653,714,484,715,629,573,263,408,436,300,544,407,432,568,536,462,485,346,610,524];
 var array_y = [18,18,181,228,60,232,34,32,26,37,65,62,228,180,91,83,83,81,88,62,35,65,52,155,23,90,94,95,230,232,15,105,37,68,47,186,186,93,14,65,22,10,230,68,18,91,226,22,150,227,89,43,76,92,62,12,187,96,78,33,35,180,151,230,151,154,95,96,31,233,39,77,79,20,30,165,65,51,18,62,96,19,150,33,79,19,35,23,210,20,180,95,184,19,76,64,36,186,73,151,26,192,153,156,24,36,165,97,85,78,77,101,184,22,177,212,210,166,79,210,150,168,45,18];

 var isPaused = false;


var firstLoad = function () {
    context.font = "15px Georgia";
    context.textAlign = "center";
}

firstLoad();

var main = function () {
    draw();
};

var draw = function () {
    // Clear Canvas
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Draw map
    context.drawImage(mapSprite, 0, 0, 954, 267);

    //draw red cross
    cross = new Image();
    cross.src = "cross.png";    
    // draw blue cross
    cross1 = new Image();
    cross1.src = "cross-blue.png";  



    var t = window.setInterval(function() {   if(!isPaused) {       event_coor();     } }, 5000);
    i=0;

    function event_coor() {
        if (i < array_x.length) {
        context.drawImage(cross, array_x[i], array_y[i], 10, 10);
        i=i+1;
    }   
    }


}

mapSprite.addEventListener('load', main);

//with jquery
$('.pause').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  isPaused = true;
});

$('.play').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  isPaused = false;
});
</script>
```

What I want to do is to change the color of the image `cross` that will be displayed under `mapSprite`, let's say displaying it in red `cross.png` and after displaying the second one, the oldest will turn to blue `cross-blue.png` at the same time. As that I will always have the last one in red to catch the attention.

How to change le last image source context.drawimage after few seconds?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT 1 : Redraw above the last one after 2seconds

```
 <script src="http://alertifyjs.com/build/alertify.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://alertifyjs.com/build/css/alertify.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://alertifyjs.com/build/css/themes/default.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<div style="width : 75%;margin : auto;">
<canvas id="Canvas" width="954" height="267"></canvas>


<button class="play">Play</button>
<button class="pause">Pause</button>

</div>

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Map sprite
var mapSprite = new Image();
mapSprite.src = "v1.png";
 var array_x = [351,315,353,352,318,485,351,748,568,645,373,350,572,374,650,240,240,320,707,235,402,539,256,410,433,405,353,745,404,320,514,322,692,474,293,418,418,690,237,513,378,478,433,405,285,429,458,622,568,536,564,389,641,534,567,454,575,482,459,539,431,327,464,374,348,520,279,378,509,516,232,744,351,710,481,540,429,642,537,459,513,689,324,463,375,747,431,265,484,591,458,460,485,407,720,483,376,520,691,376,232,413,536,430,653,714,484,715,629,573,263,408,436,300,544,407,432,568,536,462,485,346,610,524];
 var array_y = [18,18,181,228,60,232,34,32,26,37,65,62,228,180,91,83,83,81,88,62,35,65,52,155,23,90,94,95,230,232,15,105,37,68,47,186,186,93,14,65,22,10,230,68,18,91,226,22,150,227,89,43,76,92,62,12,187,96,78,33,35,180,151,230,151,154,95,96,31,233,39,77,79,20,30,165,65,51,18,62,96,19,150,33,79,19,35,23,210,20,180,95,184,19,76,64,36,186,73,151,26,192,153,156,24,36,165,97,85,78,77,101,184,22,177,212,210,166,79,210,150,168,45,18];

 var isPaused = false;


var firstLoad = function () {
    context.font = "15px Georgia";
    context.textAlign = "center";
}

firstLoad();

var main = function () {
    draw();
};

var draw = function () {
    // Clear Canvas
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Draw map
    context.drawImage(mapSprite, 0, 0, 954, 267);

    //draw red cross
    cross = new Image();
    cross.src = "cross.png";    
    // draw blue cross
    cross1 = new Image();
    cross1.src = "cross-blue.png";  



    var t = window.setInterval(function() {   if(!isPaused) {       event_coor();     } }, 5000);
    i=0;

    function event_coor() {
        if (i < array_x.length) {
        context.drawImage(cross, array_x[i], array_y[i], 10, 10);
        window.setInterval (function () { context.drawImage(cross1, array_x[i], array_y[i], 10, 10);}, 2000);
        i=i+1;
    }   
    }


}

mapSprite.addEventListener('load', main);

//with jquery
$('.pause').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  isPaused = true;
});

$('.play').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  isPaused = false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to redraw the whole scene, or if the cross is not overlapped by other elements / has solid color, just the cross.

There is no way to change the src of already rendered element, since there is no history (scene graph) of what has been drawn on canvas previously.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your answer, please look to my EDIT 1. It is possible instead to imitate the same expected behaviour by redraw above the last one the blue cross after 2s? The only problem is that there is reversal of colors : Initially i've red, after that i've blue turns to red, why ?

Comment: check out the filters api, meybe you'll find something that suits our needs on color changing in canvas https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter but the redraw is way easier.

Comment: In order to help you with debug you'll have to provide the full code since i'm not able to check why the it redraws in current shape of provided implementation

Comment: With var t = window ... you set the interval calling the function that turns the cross red, and adds a new interval to the window. I dont think this is quite intended.

Comment: i think the second oposed to the interval in you could use timeout. Beside that - check this fiddle, i guess the rest is working ok. The facebook icon gets overlapped by whatsup icon after 2 secs ( with your interval endlessly forever but : ) https://jsfiddle.net/8mevwecy/4/